# Email confirmation link specific to Email provider

Tags: php, email

I'm making a new site, and already have email confirmation code in place. But is there a way of making a "go to your inbox" link that is specific to the users' email provider? For example:

- Go to live.com if it's a @live.com email
- Go to yahoo.com if it's a @yahoo.com email

Some sort of if statement I'm guessing? Just some ideas would be good!

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$ext = array('live.com','yahoo.com');


$domain = explode('@', $email);

if ( $domain[1] == $ext[0])
{
    // Go to Live.com
} 
if( $domain[1] == $ext[1])
{
   //Go to Yahoo.com
}
```

with email is field name  in  registration form /subscribe form